# Parsing a piece of text after another piece of text (Using python Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

The HTML I want to parse is this:

```
> </td> </tr> <!--MRT--> <tr><td colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px
> Dashed #CCC"><h3>MRT Stations Nearby</h3></td></tr><tr><td
> colspan="2"><table width="602" align="center" cellpadding="0"
> cellspacing="0"><tr><td width="261"><a
> href="/property/propertynearmrt/Boon-Lay-MRT/?t=dl&mid=12" title="Boon
> Lay MRT"><strong>Boon Lay MRT</strong></a><br />Distance :0.07km </td>
```

From here, I want to get the distance (In this case 0.07km). I am also parsing the name of the station "Boon-Lay-MRT" using the following code:

```
   soup2=BeautifulSoup(webpage2) 
   for cell in soup2.findAll('h3'):
        if 'MRT Stations Nearby' == cell.text:         

            for cell2 in cell.findAllNext('strong')[0]:
                print(cell2)
```

How do I get the next bit of text (the distance)? I thought just changing the ('strong')[0] to ('br /') should work but it doesnt.

Sorry if the question is rather silly, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the input of the problem is `MRT Stations Nearby` text. The output should be `0.07km`.

In this case, the idea would be to locate the `MRT Stations Nearby` text, find the `tr` parent. From there, find the next `tr` sibling and look for the element containing `Distance` text:

```
row = soup.find(text="MRT Stations Nearby").find_parent("tr").find_next_sibling("tr")
distance = row.find(text=lambda x: x and x.startswith("Distance"))

print distance.split(":")[-1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `for cell2 in cell.findAllNext('br')[0]:` ... i don't think you need the '/' as that just means the tag is self closing

Comment: I can see what's going on ... the name is inside the `strong` tags, but the distance is after a `br` tag, hence the `br` cell is indeed empty. Alecxe's answer looks like a better direction to go in :0)